# Usar Droppable con jquery Ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hola como están? verán estoy usando jqueryUI, la función Droppable (Que sirve para arrastrar elementos). Estoy siguiendo este tutorial de la misma documentación [Tutorial](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager) y lo estoy adaptando a mi manera aquí el código

```
//Coidgo Html Grupo de botones para ser arrastrados
   <div class="group_alternative_button" id="alternative">
                        <ul class="group_drop_button">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="btn_option btn_option_list">Control</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="btn_option btn_option_list">Paz</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="btn_option btn_option_list">Alegría</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
 //Contenedor de los botones, es decir donde serán depositados
      <div class="group_alternative_button" id="answer" style="height:100px">
                    </div>
```

Hasta hai la estructura HTML ahora jquery

```
$(function(){
    var $alternative = $("#alternative"),
    $answer = $("#answer");

    $("li",$alternative).draggable({
        cancel: "a.btn_option_list",
        revert: "invalid",
        containment: "document",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move"
    });        
    $answer.droppable({
        accept: "#alternative > ul > li",
        drop: function (event,ui){
            deleteAnswer(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
    $alternative.droppable({
        accept: "#answer ul li",
        drop: function (event,ui){
            recycleAnswer(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
    function deleteAnswer($item){
        $item.fadeOut(function(){
            var $list = $("ul",$answer).length ?
            $("ul",$answer) :
                    $("<ul class='group_drop_button'/>").appendTo($answer);
        });
    }
    function recycleAnswer($item){
        $item.fadeOut(function(){
            $item
                    .appendTo($alternative)
                    .fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
```

El problema esta cuando suelto los elemento en el contenedor que los recibe desaparecen y no los veo, algo debo de estar haciendo mal o me falte algo ayuda por favor Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al final lo culmine aquí mi solucion

```
<div class="group_alternative_button" >
                        <ul class="group_drop_button" id="alternative">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="btn_option btn_option_list">Control</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="btn_option btn_option_list">Paz</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="btn_option btn_option_list">Alegría</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Jquery unos pequeños cambios

```
$(function(){
    var $alternative = $("#alternative");
    var $answer = $("#answer");
    $("li",$alternative).draggable({
        cancel: "a.btn_option",
        revert: "invalid",
        containment: "document",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move"
    });        
    $answer.droppable({
        accept: '#alternative > li',
        drop: function (event,ui){
            deleteAnswer(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
    $alternative.droppable({
        accept: "#answer li",
        drop: function (event,ui){
            recycleAnswer(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
    function deleteAnswer($item){
        $item.fadeOut(function(){
            var $list = $("ul",$answer).length ?
            $("ul",$answer) :
                    $("<ul class='group_rest_button'/>").appendTo($answer);
            $item.appendTo($list).fadeIn();
        });
    }
    function recycleAnswer($item){
        $item.fadeOut(function(){
            $item
                    .appendTo($alternative)
                    .fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
```

lo que sucedía es que no estaba agregando el elemento al Html entonces solo desaparecía con un display none bueno aquí esta para quien le sea de utilidad

Comment: Oye jonathan puedes ayudarme en mi pregunta [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168994/problema-con-draggable-en-jquery)